# get response code brain tree payment gateway

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I have sign up for the testing sandbox at brain tree and they have provided the php kit also and that is works well. and I am able to submit the payment over there using the following code rest all codes are by default no change.

I am able to execute payment successfully at my hosting url and I am facing problem in only getting the response codes I want to get the response codes for faild or successfull transaction if any help can be apricated.

```
<?php
require_once('lib/Braintree.php');
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('rksddb2nb');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('jrsdgf');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('ee001sd18687');
function braintree_text_field($label, $name, $result) {
echo('<div>' . $label . '</div>');
$fieldValue = isset($result) ? $result->valueForHtmlField($name) : '';
echo('<div><input type="text" name="' . $name .'" value="' . $fieldValue . '" />    </div>');
$errors = isset($result) ? $result->errors->onHtmlField($name) : array();
foreach($errors as $error) {
    echo('<div style="color: red;">' . $error->message . '</div>');
}
echo("\n");
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Braintree Transparent Redirect</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
$result = Braintree_TransparentRedirect::confirm($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
if (isset($result) && $result->success) { ?>
<h1>Braintree Transparent Redirect Response</h1>
<?php $transaction = $result->transaction; ?>
<table>
<tr><td>transaction id</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->id); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>transaction status</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->status); ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>transaction amount</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->amount); ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>customer first name</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->customerDetails->firstName); ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>customer last name</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->customerDetails->lastName); ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>customer email</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->customerDetails->email); ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>credit card number</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->creditCardDetails->maskedNumber); ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>expiration date</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->creditCardDetails->expirationDate); ?></td></tr>
        </table>
    <?php
    } else {
        if (!isset($result)) { $result = null; } ?>
        <h1>Braintree Transparent Redirect Example</h1>
        <?php if (isset($result)) { ?>
            <div style="color: red;"><?php echo $result->errors->deepSize(); ?> error(s)</div>
        <?php } ?>
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo Braintree_TransparentRedirect::url() ?>" >
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Customer</legend>
                <?php braintree_text_field('First Name', 'transaction[customer][first_name]', $result); ?>
                <?php braintree_text_field('Last Name', 'transaction[customer][last_name]', $result); ?>
                <?php braintree_text_field('Email', 'transaction[customer][email]', $result); ?>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Payment Information</legend>

                <?php braintree_text_field('Credit Card Number', 'transaction[credit_card][number]', $result); ?>
                <?php braintree_text_field('Expiration Date (MM/YY)', 'transaction[credit_card][expiration_date]', $result); ?>
                <?php braintree_text_field('CVV', 'transaction[credit_card][cvv]', $result); ?>
            </fieldset>

            <?php $tr_data = Braintree_TransparentRedirect::transactionData(
                array('redirectUrl' => "http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ":" . $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] . parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH),
                'transaction' => array('amount' => '10.00', 'type' => 'sale'))) ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="tr_data" value="<?php echo $tr_data ?>" />

            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
```

Comment: i checked out that they are using the clsss system to submit the payment

Answer (score 0):

try this example exactly as given. it works well for success and error conditions.
https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/guide/getting_paid
or you can try ajax example link given at the bottom of page. both are working  properly